# How to use RequestConfig based on @umijs/max to make the front end insensitive to refresh tokens

Tags: typescript, antd, umi

Here's how I think about it: After a user's login, they have got two tokens (access and refresh) from the server. Before sending a request, if the access token is found to have expired, it waits to obtain a new access token from the server before continuing the current request.

May I ask who can provide reference code? Thanks!

Looking for reference code